# Error in tests with Angular 6 and Jest - TypeError: testing.TestBed.inject is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs, angular-testing-library

When running the tests on my project when trying to render the component, the tests fail with the following error:

`TypeError: testing.TestBed.inject is not a function`

This is the test component:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: 'counter',
    template: `
      <button (click)="decrement()">-</button>
      <span data-testid="count">Current Count: {{ counter }}</span>
      <button (click)="increment()">+</button>
    `,
  })
  export class CounterComponent {
    @Input() counter = 0
  
    increment() {
      this.counter += 1
    }
  
    decrement() {
      this.counter -= 1
    }
  }
```

This is the test with testing library for Angular:

```
import {render, screen } from '@testing-library/angular'
import {CounterComponent} from './prueba.component'

describe('Counter', () => {
  test('should render counter', async () => {
    await render(CounterComponent, {
      componentProperties: {counter: 5},
    })
    expect(screen.getByText('Current Count: 5')).toBeTruthy();
  })
})
```

Comment: Maybe you're using a too recent version of `testing-library`, most recent versions won't be compatible with Angular 6. I remember using `@testing-library/angular` version 8 and it was OK with Angular 6

Answer (score 0):

What version of @testing-library/angular are you on?
I think the version isn't compatible with Angular v6.
Try upgrading/downgrading testing library.